# C arrays allocating on the stack with an extra pointer

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to C, but have a fairly good understanding of compilers and how stack frames work and the like. I'm trying to understand how C arrays are allocated on the stack whilst also being pointers. For example, take the code:

```
int a = 101;
int b[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

I'm told that b is a pointer here. e.g. '*(b+1) = 3;' is the same as 'b[2] = 3'. Does this mean that the stack frame here has an integer for a, an pointer for b and an array (of 5*sizeof(int) bytes) which is pointed to by b (I've called this situation A) or just an integer for a and an array for b (I've called this situation B).

I've created a picture to make this slightly more clear:
[image]

If situation A is true, why have the C designers chosen to implement arrays so differently to variables? Doesn't this mean that an array needs to constantly have an extra memory lookup for the pointer to get it's address?

Comment: to start with, `*(b+1) = 2;` (not 3)

Comment: C does not enforce a specific allocation scheme for objects. Neither does it require a heap, nor a stack. And the question is too broad. Also: arrays are **not** pointers! Whoever told you should learn the language before teaching it.

Comment: Arrays *decay* to pointers. They aren't themselves pointers.

Comment: What happens mostly is situation B, but this is an implementation detail and the compiler can use a different layout. I've never seen situation A, there is absolutely no reason to implement arrays like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that the stack frame here has an integer for a, an pointer for b and an array (of 5*sizeof(int) bytes) which is pointed to by b

```
int b[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Your `b` is an array, not a pointer. So `b` is a block of memory holding five consecutive integers.

If you declare an additional pointer

```
int *c = b;
```

Then that would resemble to what you describe in situation B, ie you have a pointer that points to the beginning of an array.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't have a notion of a *stack*. Using the correct terminology, we can say that

`int b[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

has *automatic storage duration*.

It just happens that *array indexing* is exactly equivalent to dereferencing a pointer, and *pointer arithmetic* is valid within arrays.

So `b[2]` and `*(b + 2)` are equivalent. The designers of C did this for clarity.

What happens on the "stack" is an implementation choice, not a language one.

The relationship between `a` and `b` is not particularly relevant. Note that you cannot "reach" `a` by some curious indexing of `b` (and vice-versa). The behaviour on attempting to do that is *undefined*.